# Where can i read about ruby pkg-config and .pc files?

Tags: ruby

It seems that ruby searches for native extensions dependencies via pkg-config gem that in turn search for some .pc files with meta information. Is it some place where all this machinery is explained and written down? I searched web, but it seems that native extensions build process is accepted as some "magic" :(

Comment: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Extending_Ruby_Creating_a_Makefile_with_extconf.rb.html

Comment: @raam86 Thanks a lot - this article indeed contains very usefull information about pkg-config working. But no information about `.pc` files :(. Maybe you also know where it's documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pkg-config's home page is [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/). From there you can find a link to [Dan Nicholson's Guide to pkg-config](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html).